# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on 9.0.2 XP0

Tags: xconnect

**Environment details**:  9.0.2 XP0

**What I am trying to do**: I am trying to create an xConnect client from Sitecore context.

**What is the issue I am facing**:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

[image]

**Points I have checked**:
1. Sitecore client is working with Https without any warning.
[image]

2. xConnect is opening with Https in browser properly.
   [image]
3. The certificate thumbprint is according to the certificate applied in the Connection string of Sitecore client and App-config of xConnect.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Please suggest what else I should check.
**Edit 1**:
Also checked at `sc9u2.xconnect\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config`. The thumbprint value is same.

Comment: please check the sitecore instance application pool has full permission to access xconnect _Client certificate

Comment: @DS- I have provided access to Everyone over this certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

1. The valid thumbprint should be the thumbprint from `sc9u2.xconnect_client` certificate. The cert `sc9u2.xconnect` is the SSL cert for the site. The _client cert is the one being used to encrypt the message. Update your configs (sitecore and xconnect) to use the right certificate thumb print. Remember that if you copy the cert from certificate manager, it includes some special characters you can't see. echo it in powershell to get the real value without the hidden characters.
2. Right click on `sc9u2.xconnect_client` and click Manage Private Keys. In the security popup, add the app pool user for your sitecore website. If this is dev, you can just add `Everyone`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks will check and revert.

Comment: In case it's not dev or you want to limit permissions, "local service" is the user the Service is run with, read permissions are sufficient. Even better would be to run the service with a specific user and set permissions to that user.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure below things are in place.

1- Thumbprint iscorrect in xconnect app.config and CD/CM server's connectionstring.config files.

2- Make sure, you have given the permission for certificate in MMC for the user which is used in apppool.

3- xconnect certificates are installed in CD and CM Servers.

Thanks